# Unable to su into an account: could not open session

Tags: users, su

in my Linux machine - red-hat

I successfully  to login to different users as the following

```
su - userC
[machine@Linux ~]$ pwd
[machine@Linux ~]$ /Users/userC
```

but only in one user I get the following

```
su - UserA
Creating directory '/User/UserA'.
could not open session
```

please advice from where I get the message "could not open session"

what could be the problem ?

Comment: what is the output of `getent passwd` and are you using LDAP, flat files, or something else? It really looks like UserA's shell is set to `/sbin/nologin`

Comment: Does that directory exist? Is the difference in case on `/Users/userC` and `/Users/UserA` a typo? Intentional? The problem?

Comment: yes I already tried the getent passwd and the output is fine

Comment: if I am using LDAP , not sure but the file  /etc/openldap/ldap.conf exist in my machine so I guess yes

Comment: but which file or app  send the mesg - could not open session?

Comment: is it possible that LDAP will block the USER?

Comment: I don't think you've answered Etan Reisner's question. Does the home directory for the user that gets this message exist? I suspect that it doesn't (or it's not setup correctly) and that's why you see the "Creating directory" message. You need to work out why the directory isn't there (or isn't working as it should). You may be able to find clues in /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 9):

```
root@hostname # su - oracle
could not open session

root@hostname # grep oracle.*nofile /etc/security/limits.conf
oracle          -       nofile          unlimited
```

set nofile in `limits.conf` to some number instead of unlimited:

```
root@hostname # vi /etc/security/limits.conf
root@hostname # grep oracle.*nofile /etc/security/limits.conf
oracle          -       nofile          65536
root@hostname # su - oracle
-bash-4.1$ id
uid=201(oracle) gid=5504(oinstall) groups=5504(oinstall),251(dba),5502(asmdba),5505(oper)
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: On my system, the soft OS limit is:

```cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max # 512000```

Which suggests you need the line ```oracle - nofile  512000``` instead

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me, in my case su was working for some users.
So, I checked the content of /etc/pam.d/su and it had the following two lines :

***session         include         system-auth***

***session         optional        pam_xauth.so***

I commented out the first one, restarted the session and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: This worked, but any idea why this needs to be changed?

Comment: ya, this also worked for me.  But I'm truly curious about why this is happening.  As an additional layer of the problem, this ONLY occured when I had nofile limits set in /etc/security/limits.conf for the user it was effecting -- if I removed EITHER the `session include system-auth` in pam.d/su OR the nofile limits in /etc/security/limits.conf the Su would start working again.

Answer (score 5):

commenting "session required pam_limits.so" in all files in "/etc/pam.d"
solves

- su: cannot open session: Permission denied
- runuser: cannot open session: Permission denied

(OL7.7)

```
sed -i -r 's/^(session\s+required\s+pam_limits.so)/#\1/' /etc/pam.d/*
```

Comment: I encountered this problem while running Oracle Linux 8.5 in a Docker container, and this solved the problem for me. It's not clear to me whether there are any security implications for making this change, but, alas, I do not care given my specific use-case. So, thank you!!!

Comment: Also worked for me with docker running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago). Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

I was playing with docker and `oraclelinux:7-slim`, to install an Oracle Database. After installing oracle-database-preinstall-19c package, I stopped being able to `su -` into oracle account. Here some talk about "nofile unlimited" in `limits.conf`. I tried that and it didn't work. Commenting `session include system-auth` line in `/etc/pam.d/su` works.

However, before I installed the package, the configuration was all the same and I was able to do `su - oracle`. Even after installed the package, if I create a new user belonging to the same groups as oracle I can `su` into their account. So it had to be something that the package changed.

After some investigation I discovered that the packages installs `oracle-database-preinstall-19c.conf` in `/etc/security/limits.d/` and that file has all the oracle limits configuration. Only when I commented the following line, was I able to `su` into oracle account:

**oracle hard memlock 134217728**

This sets the memlock to 128Gb.Tried to put smaller values without success. Only when I commented.

So now you know that this is the cause. But of course, if you comment `session include system-auth` line in `/etc/pam.d/su` it works too.

Answer (score 3):

If "nofile" is set to "unlimited" in /etc/security/limits.conf (or in files in limits.d) then the user cannot login.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting out 'session include system-auth' worked for me.

env: docker oraclelinux:latest, after installing oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall.x86_64 package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `pam_limits.so` line has tabs like this:

```
session^I^Irequired^Ipam_limits.so$
```

When this line is added, the tabs are important.

```
sed -i '$a session^I^Irequired^Ipam_limits.so' /etc/pam.d/su
```

If the tabs are missing, then you will see something like this:

```
[ azureadmin]# su - ALOGIN
Last login: Fri Jun 11 08:42:32 CDT 2021 on pts/0
su: cannot open session: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same error.  "sudo su -" did not work, nor did "su -", however "sudo -iu root" or "sudo /bin/bash" did "work" ("sudo /bin/bash" isn't quite doing the same thing, in terms of environment variables, so I feel a little dubious calling this a work around).  The answer wasn't the "nofile" limit, nor was the answer the permissions on /etc/pam.d/system* files.  The answer in my case was that /var/log/btmp was corrupted.

```
# cat /dev/null > /var/log/btmp
```

Answer (score -1):

Some times it happens to me with error "could not open session" and It works with just type

```
sudo bash
```